# Selecting rows from a sparse matrix based on the index of a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Suppose I have a panda dataframe of shape = (2,500,000, M) and a scipy csr sparse matrix of shape (2,500,000, N).

Each row of the dataframe and sparse matrix describes one entity. They are already ordered such that row 1 of the dataframe is describing an entity that is also found in row 1 of the sparse matrix. So now the dataframe has a fast mechanism to do filtering (`catalogue.where(catalogue.some_column != ''`), but how do I find the respective rows in the sparse matrix given the filtered dataframe?

Assume the dataframe is called a `catalogue`, and the sparse matrix is called a `collection`

```
def collection_filter_row(catalogue_filtered, catalogue_index_full, collection):
    return scipy.sparse.vstack(ThreadPool(100).map(
        functools.partial(collection_get_row,
             catalogue_index=tuple(catalogue_index_full),
             collection=collection),
        tuple(catalogue_filtered.index.values)))

def collection_get_row(document_id, catalogue_index, collection):
    return collection.getrow(catalogue_index.index(document_id))

collection_partial = partial(
    collection_filter_row,
    catalogue_index_full=catalogue.index.values,
    collection=pickle.load(open('collection-tfidf', 'rb')))
criteria = catalogue['criteria'].where(catalogue.criteria != '')
collection_state = collection_partial(criteria)
```

but even with any sort of multiprocessing (gevent, threadpool), it is still slow to pick the respective rows, am I doing anything wrong (or rather, is there a faster way of doing this)?

Comment: `vstack` is the `sparse` version?

Comment: Do you have a sense of which steps are taking time?  Without the pool, is `collection.getrow` a slow step?  Or `catalogue_index.index`?  The multiprocessing stuff may be working, but it obscures the sparse indexing step - which seems to be the part you asking about.

Comment: Have you explored selecting multiple rows from `collection` at once?  How does it scale?

Comment: @hpaulj (on vstack) yes, (which is slow?) I also attempted to select multiple rows from collection at once, but the slowness comes when trying to compile which row to return from the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow found a faster way to solve this problem. Start by creating a dictionary of `catalogue` index => `collection` index.

```
index_dict = dict(zip(
    catalogue.index.values.tolist(),
    range(collection.shape[0])))
```

Then my `collection_filter_row` becomes

```
def collection_filter_row(catalogue_filtered, index_dict, collection):
    return collection[[index_dict[document_id]
                       for document_id
                       in catalogue_filtered.index.values.tolist()]]
```

In order to return a subset of collection, instead of using `catalogue.where()` I really should be using `catalogue.loc[catalogue.some_column != '']`, so the proper call to `collection_filter_row` is then

```
collection_sub = collection_filter_row(
    catalogue.loc[catalogue.some_column != ''],
    index_dict,
    collection)
```

much much faster than the original method shown in question